# How do I align three animated progress bars with images horizontally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Here is a jsfiddle of the progress bar aligned vertically. How would I make them align horizontally and centered?

https://jsfiddle.net/bLe0jLar/

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper > #bar,
#bar2,
#bar3 {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper > #bar,
#bar2,
#bar3,
.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the progress bar are aligned **vertically**. How to make them align
>   **horizontally** and centered?

The only thing you need is to change your `wrapper` rule to this

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

*I suggest a few changes in the CSS (see notes). Also, no need to combine the child selector `>` with an id selector `#` like this `.wrapper > #bar`, as there is only one element with that id*

[Updated fiddle with suggested changes](https://jsfiddle.net/eu12atdw/)

Stack snippet

```js
var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'
});

circle.animate(1);

var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar2', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'
});

circle.animate(1);

var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar3', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'
});

circle.animate(1);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#bar,                      /* changed ".wrapper > #bar" to "#bar" */
#bar2,
#bar3 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 5px;           /* add a small gap between the circles */
}

/* .wrapper > #bar,          removed this rule as it is not needed
#bar2,                       
#bar3,
.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}                                                                  */

.wrapper img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;             /* added, so they scale on smaller screens */
}

.wrapper svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/master/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="bar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/391FcV0.png" /></div>
  <div id="bar2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/NtqQEKF.png" /></div>
  <div id="bar3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/NGROIlB.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `width` and `height` to `img` and use `flex` to get center also remove `height` and `width` from `wrapper` class to get center.

Update following css part

```
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-flow:column;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```js
var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'
});

circle.animate(1);

var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar2', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'
});

circle.animate(1);

var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar3', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'
});

circle.animate(1);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper>#bar,
#bar2,
#bar3 {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper>#bar,
#bar2,
#bar3,
.wrapper img {
  /*   width: 100%;
  height: 100%; */
}

.wrapper img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/master/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="bar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/391FcV0.png" /></div>
  <div id="bar2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/NtqQEKF.png" /></div>
  <div id="bar3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/NGROIlB.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle - **[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bLe0jLar/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use [inline blocks](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) to solve your question.
Then it is possible to align blocks horizontally so similar as inline elements using `text-align` CSS property of a parent container.

```js
var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'
});

circle.animate(1);

var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar2', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'
});

circle.animate(1);

var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar3', {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  color: '#000'
});

circle.animate(1);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align:center;
}
.wrapper > div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/master/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="bar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/391FcV0.png" /></div>
  <div id="bar2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/NtqQEKF.png" /></div>
  <div id="bar3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/NGROIlB.png" /></div>
</div>
```